# \label{REF} printing REF instead of building reference

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I'm writing my thesis manuscript and I have a weird problem with the \label{} command. I'm using the *document* class.

The problem is that using the following code

```
\chapter[name]{name}
\markboth{name}
\label{REF}
```

I don't get the desired output, that is a reference labelled as REF, but instead I get REF printed just below the title, just like:

> name (in title format)
>
> REF

The weirdest thing is that this is happening only from the fourth chapter on, while for previous chapter the same exact format worked as it was supposed to. No other changes are present in the way different chapters are called into the main .tex file or whatever. The structure for introducing each chapter was simply copied from the first employed format which was working good.

Comment: \markboth has two arguments, so it eats the `\label`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, I didn't notice and it was driving me crazy